# Is there a faster way of importing 8m+ rows?

Tags: mysql, import, time

I'm creating a new feature on my website in order to provide player locations (my website is for a multiplayer gaming service), and am going to use a simple IP lookup in my database.

For this I need to import an [IP location CSV (country  IP address to city)](https://db-ip.com/db/) into my local MySQL database*, but it's taking a while:

[image]

I started importing the data roughly 40 minutes ago, and it looks like it'll take a few hours.

Is there a faster way of importing the data. I'm currently using MySQL Workbench and it uses no more than 15% of my CPU (using an Intel Xeon X5650 with 16GB RAM on Windows 10 Pro x64), so the issue may be that MySQL Workbench simply isn't optimized for a data import of this scale.

Is there a faster way of importing this data?

---

*Will be Amazon Aurora when I have the money to do so, so I'm not worried about the query speed.

Comment: Try disabling indexes and parallel insertion possibly using some script.

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem. Instead of rolling your own, consider using an [existing service](https://www.google.ca/search?q=geoip+api), it will save you not only loading time but also development and maintenance efforts.

Comment: the `load data infile` statement should be optimized for this. No idea if WB uses transactions properly (if your table is even InnoDB) etc.

Comment: I/O delay?  Ethernet delay?  Low value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It should be about 11G for your system.